# How to get data from API based on other values types

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I have a question, that i can't resolve. I have a API reques fere i need to get Image from that API.
I have Images section fhere i have something like this:

```
[{Id: 16, Type: "COVER",…}
 {Id: 18, Type: "HIGHLIGHTS",…}
 {Id: 23, Type: "COVER",…}
 {Id: 24, Type: "FRAME",…}
]
```

I need to get my image `URL` from type `FRAME`
In React i did get title, and ID, but this was easy. I am stuck on Image

```
return (
        <Fragment>
          {data.map((movie) => {
            return (
              <div key={movie.Id} className='Home__Card-content'>
                <img src={movie.Images.Url} alt='poster' />
                <h2>{movie.Title}</h2>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </Fragment>
      );
```

Thanks for any help

API response

[image: API response]

Comment: what is your api response?

Comment: In edit. I added a screen of API response

Comment: You have multiple images per Id in your response. Which one do you want to pick?

Comment: movie.Images[0].Url, as images is your array.

Comment: The one with type :"FRAME"

Comment: yes, but not always "FRAME" is [0]. It has diffrent index

Comment: use `find` method on Array: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: And next time on, pls add all necessary details in the question itself rather than having ppl ask probing questions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is indeterminate that always **FRAME** is the first element or not, you'll need to `find` it in array.

e.g. :

```js
movie.Images.find(img => img.ImageTypeCode === 'FRAME').Url
```

Comment: Bit of suger - `(({ ImageTypeCode }) => ImageTypeCode === 'FRAME')`

Answer (score 1):

Filter your images array for `ImageTypeCoe` as `FRAME` using `filter()` method.

```
<img src={getImages(movie.Images)[0].Url} alt='poster' />

const getImage (images) => images.filter((data) => data.ImageTypeCoe === "FRAME");
```

> Using find() method:

```
<img src={getImages(movie.Images).Url} alt='poster' />

const getImage (images) => images.find((data) => data.ImageTypeCoe === "FRAME");
```

Comment: Thasnk. This was helpful. In my case answer belowe was bestter for me :)

Comment: you can also use find method

Answer (score 1):

You can use find for that.

The find() method returns the value of the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function. If no values satisfy the testing function, undefined is returned.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

```
let url = "";
const frame = movie.Images.find(x => x.ImageTypeCode === 'FRAME');
if (frame){
   url =  frame.URL;
}
```